# Android Studio - How To Add A Fragment? (January 2019 Update)

Tags: android-studio, android-fragmentactivity

The new Android Studio update came out sometime last week (January 2019 Version 3.3).
In the previous version you'd be able to create new project and click a checkbox that said "add a fragment". 
Unfortunately, in the new update I can't find this checkbox or anything related.

Do we now have to add fragments by hand? Or is there a way to create a project with a fragment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.
Before Version 3.3 you were able to create a new project and set the basic activity as a fragment. Since Version 3.3 update it no longer gives you the option to create a fragment when creating a new project.

So this is how you're supposed to do it:

Create a new project with whatever activities you want.

Switch to Android View -> Right click on "app" under the navigator -> New -> Activity -> Basic Activity
Now a separate window will open up and you're able to select the checkbox "Use a fragment".

Comment: I still can't find it. The option is missing. Android Studio 3.6 here. Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it while retaining the current Activity is to auto generate the fragment using

```
New (or Alt+INS) -> Fragment -> Fragment (any of the subtypes).
```

this will generate your frament xml layout together with the code stub.

Then in the main_activity.xml replace the "helloWorld TextView" (if you create an empty activity) or "content_main.xml" (if you create the one with FAB) with the following...

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.example.MainFragment" 
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />
```

assuming you name it as MainFragment in the com.example package.